# Duvida sobre o envio do mail php

Tags: php, email

Ao receber um e-mail enviado pela função mail do php, a mesma aparece o e-mail configurado na função como remetente e aparece esse nome que esta grifado, alguém sabe me dizer por que?
é um servidor? é confiável usar?

[image: e-mail recebido no gmail]

Comment: http://www.dkim.org/ DKIM é uma especificação do IETF que define um mecanismo para autenticação de e-mail http://antispam.br/admin/dkim/

Comment: Aahhh entendi, muito obrigada!